# Parameterized Kubernetes manifest files?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I'm learning Kubernetes, coming from an AWS/CloudFormation background to set up my company's infrastructure. One of the strengths of CloudFormation is the use a template that can be parameterized for re-used. So I can use the **same** template to deploy all our microservices in Fargate, giving it the Docker image, version, CPU/memory counts, etc for each microservice.

When using Kubernetes manifest files, is there good way to "templatize" manifest files? I've read  [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/29/introducing-kustomize-template-free-configuration-customization-for-kubernetes/), but as the title says it's "template-free," and to use it for all our microservices, I'll need multiple `/someapp/...` directory trees, which is NOT what I want.

Sure I can use `sed` but that seems archaic. I can use `yq` to massage my yaml files, but this also seems archaic. For either approach, changing a manifest file entails changing the corresponding `sed` and `yp` commands.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? How about 3rd party tools like [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/deploy-to-kubernetes/kubernetes-templating/)? How about `helm`? (I haven't looked at it yet.).

Comment: I would recommend Kustomize rather than Helm

Comment: Why is that @Jonas? Maybe you can put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I educated myself more about `helm` and it looks like it has these features that I need

- packaging
- templating
- release management, including rollbacks

so I'll study it more.